# How to split one column to multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server

so my question is 
run a query and get my result like this

```
WEEKS   PRODUCT     SELL
Week-1  Product-A   34
Week-1  Product-B   40
Week-1  Product-C   38
Week-1  Product-D   20
Week-2  Product-A   27
Week-2  Product-B   25
Week-2  Product-C   22
Week-2  Product-D   39
Week-3  Product-A   33
Week-3  Product-B   19
Week-3  Product-C   43
Week-3  Product-D   36
Week-4  Product-A   21
Week-4  Product-B   26
Week-4  Product-C   33
Week-4  Product-D   39
Week-5  Product-A   43
Week-5  Product-B   30
Week-5  Product-C   40
Week-5  Product-D   24
Week-6  Product-A   42
Week-6  Product-B   25
Week-6  Product-C   44
Week-6  Product-D   22
Week-7  Product-A   47
Week-7  Product-B   39
Week-7  Product-C   27
Week-7  Product-D   17
Week-8  Product-A   39
Week-8  Product-B   39
Week-8  Product-C   44
Week-8  Product-D   44
Week-9  Product-A   44
Week-9  Product-B   21
Week-9  Product-C   31
Week-9  Product-D   26
Week-10 Product-A   42
Week-10 Product-B   31
Week-10 Product-C   20
Week-10 Product-D   25
Week-11 Product-A   24
Week-11 Product-B   35
Week-11 Product-C   28
Week-11 Product-D   28
Week-12 Product-A   30
Week-12 Product-B   27
Week-12 Product-C   43
Week-12 Product-D   24
```

but i want my result like this

```
Week-1  Product-A   34  Product-B   40  Product-C   38  Product-D   20
Week-2  Product-A   27  Product-B   25  Product-C   22  Product-D   39
Week-3  Product-A   33  Product-B   19  Product-C   43  Product-D   36
Week-4  Product-A   21  Product-B   26  Product-C   33  Product-D   39
Week-5  Product-A   43  Product-B   30  Product-C   40  Product-D   24
Week-6  Product-A   42  Product-B   25  Product-C   44  Product-D   22
Week-7  Product-A   47  Product-B   39  Product-C   27  Product-D   17
Week-8  Product-A   39  Product-B   39  Product-C   44  Product-D   44
Week-9  Product-A   44  Product-B   21  Product-C   31  Product-D   26
Week-10 Product-A   42  Product-B   31  Product-C   20  Product-D   25
Week-11 Product-A   24  Product-B   35  Product-C   28  Product-D   28
Week-12 Product-A   30  Product-B   27  Product-C   43  Product-D   24
```

can i get my result like this 
thank you

Comment: Tag the only DBMS that you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select weeks,
       sum(case when product = 'Product-A' then sell end) as sell_a,
       sum(case when product = 'Product-B' then sell end) as sell_b,
       sum(case when product = 'Product-C' then sell end) as sell_c,
       sum(case when product = 'Product-D' then sell end) as sell_d
from t
group by weeks
order by weeks;
```